# Disable boot on secondary drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, hard-drive, boot

So I have two 2TB drives in my computer, both have windows on it, one with windows 7 and one with windows 8 pro, the problem is that the hard drive with windows 7 on it seems to always want to boot and to boot into windows 8 I need to select that HD on start up, I have changed the boot priority but it still does it. I can't simply delete that partition on the win7 hd as I need some of the software on it. Is there a way I can disable the boot on the win7 HD and restore it later on if needed? For example changing a critical file name or something like that so I can change it back later if needed?

Comment: Why not just update the boot loader to also provide the option to boot to your Windows 7 installation

Comment: Instructions? EasyBCD doesn't seem to want to do it.

Comment: You might have to do it by hand. There are lots of questions on this subject. Before I post the same instructions that already exist are you sure the answers already on this subject don't apply to you?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do that at all, or even get special software for it.

You can select which disk to boot every time you start up the computer by pressing F12 over and over until the boot menu appears. (Depending on your computer model, it could be F10, F9, or F11)

Comment: In the question thats exactly what I said I was doing, ps, for my computer it is F8

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the SATA cables of the two disks, that will revert the priority.

The other thing I can think of is:

1. unplug the hard drive with windows 8
2. to fix your boot loader again on the hard drive with windows 7
3. replug the disk with windows 8.